# How can i change the background color of the chart area from syncfusion chart?

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion

I am trying to change the back color of the chart area from Syncfusion in angular typescrypt , so far the only thing i have managed to do is change the whole chart color while i only want to change the part where the columns, bars , or lines are rendered. I have tried allredy using chartArea.background on the html and on the typescript. Maby i am doing something wring but nothing have worked so far

```
typeScrypt
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { values } from './chart.model.service/chart-data.model.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string | undefined
  data: any
  public primaryXAxis!: Object;
  primaryYAxis: Object | undefined
  tableColor: string | undefined
  chartArea: any
 

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = values;
    this.title = this.data.tittle
    this.chartSettigs();
    this.tableColor = "#6be7ed"
  }

  chartSettigs() {

     this.chartArea = {
      border: {
          width: 50
      }
    
      
  };

    this.primaryXAxis = {
      valueType: 'Category',

    };
    this.primaryYAxis = {
      labelFormat: '${value}K'
    };


  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div fxLayout="column">


  <ejs-chart 
   background="{{tableColor}}"
    height="500"
    id="chart-container"
    [primaryXAxis]='primaryXAxis'
    [primaryYAxis]='primaryYAxis'
    [title]='title'>

      <e-series-collection >
       
          <e-series 
          [dataSource]='data'
           type='Line'
            xName='weight'
            yName='age' 
            name='Sales'>
          </e-series>
       
      </e-series-collection>

  </ejs-chart>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: I have eddited the code  it contains the html and the typescript , the data source is not important sence i just want to change the chartArea color

Answer (score 0):

We would like to let you know that we can achieve your requirement using background property in the chartArea of the chart and its working fine. Based on your requirement we have prepared a sample and also attached the UG link for your reference. Please find the sample and screenshot below.

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqvzny?file=app.component.html

UG link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/api/chart/chartArea/#background

Code Snippet:

```
App.component.html: 
  
<ejs-chart [chartArea]="chartArea" > 
// add your additional code here 
</ejs-chart> 
 
App.component.ts: 
 
public chartArea: Object = { 
    border: { 
      width: 0 
    }, 
    background: "#FFFF99" 
  }; 
// add your additional code here
```

Screenshot:
[image]